# Barra de progresso em sistema web

Tags: progress-bar

alguém conhece uma forma de fazer uma barra de progresso em sistema web? No caso a minha barra de progresso não é para upload de arquivo, é uma tarefa que demora um bocado, aí seria legal uma barra de progresso para o usuário não achar que travou. Eu já pesquisei de tudo, mas não obtive sucesso.
No caso o meu sistema é em PHP, mas acho que não tem jeito de fazer isso em PHP, porque no PHP eu não consigo ler o estado de uma requisição enquanto ela não terminar. Eu pensei que talvez eu pudesse conseguir fazer isso em NodeJS, mas eu não tenho conhecimento nenhum em node no momento. Alguém sabe me falar se seria possível com Node e por onde começar?

Comment: Coloque a parte do seu código que requer essa implementação.

Answer (score 1):

Marcos,

Sua pergunta está muito genérica, não sei como está estruturado, mas para acompanhar o progresso de envio de um arquivo você pode usar algo assim:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var arquivo = document.getElementById('arquivoParaEnvio').files[0];
formData.append('arquivoParaEnvio', arquivo);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('post', '/uploadURL', true);

xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
  if (e.lengthComputable) {
    var progresso = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
    console.log(progresso + " %");
  }
};
```

---

Não sei se é o caso, mas existe o **node-upload-progress** que é um módulo do Node.js para gerenciar upload e seu progresso:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-upload-progress

Aqui você encontra um exemplo completo da utilização do módulo:

- https://github.com/phstc/node-upload-progress/tree/master/examples/progress

---

Há também uma biblioteca javascript **express-upload-progress** que gerencia progresso de upload e é estilizada com Bootstrap: https://github.com/zemirco/express-upload-progress

Answer (score 1):

Não é para upload de arquivo, é para atualizar o andamento de uma requisição que demora muito. Eu já consegui resolver.
Mas só pra constar, a ideia era ir pegando o status de uma requisição que demora muito para o usuário saber o que está acontecendo. Para isso eu escrevo na sessão o quanto da minha tarefa já foi processada e coloco um ajax para ser chamado a cada 5 segundos por exemplo. A lógica já estava montada, mas estava travando o ajax porque eu estava mantendo a session aberta. Então eu descobri que era só fechar a session com session_write_close() após escrever os dados que o ajax não trava mais.

Obrigado galera.